# Cant get ejs page to render

Tags: node.js, ejs

I want to get my news.ejs page to render when i click its link, but i get a error called "Cannot GET /news.ejs"

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

express()
  .use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
  .set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  .set('view engine', 'ejs')
  .get('/', (req, res) => res.render('pages/index'))
  .get('/news', (req, res) => res.render('pages/news'))
  .listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Listening on ${ PORT }`))
```

Comment: add line const ejs = require('ejs');

Comment: it doesnt work for me ,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have this code and working fine

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express()
const path = require('path')

const ejs = require('ejs');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', ejs)
app.get('/', (req, res) => res.render('privacypolicy.ejs'))
app.get('/news', (req, res) => res.render('rulesnregulations.ejs'))

//app.use('/', indexRouter)
const PORT = 5000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log('it started on 5000'))
```

privacypolicy.ejs & rulesnregulations.ejs these two files are under **views** folder

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are linking to `/news` and not `/news.ejs`. If you want `/news.ejs` to be accessible, you will have to change the path that you are registering.